# Reading after critical region

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, atomic, memory-model

I have an `int num = 2` protected by a  `std::mutex mut`. I write over `num` in one thread and then read `num` in a second thread.

```
// writer thread
mut.lock();
num = 5;
mut.unlock();
```

```
// reader thread
mut.lock();
mut.unlock();
int num_copy = num;
```

If the `mut.unlock()` in the writer thread executes before the `mut.lock()` in the reader thread, will `num_copy` always equal 5?

Comment: Did you mean `mut.lock(); int num_copy = num; mut.unlock();`?

Comment: no (comments must be at least 15 characters in length.)

Comment: Yes, it will, regardless of other comments.

Comment: @273K: The reader could take and release the lock before the writer thread takes the lock, either reading the old value or if you're unlucky having the read and write run at the same time.  This can be data-race UB if there's nothing else known about timing.  With the read inside the reader's critical section, you're guaranteed to get either `2` or `5`, depending on which wins the race to take the lock.  But if we somehow know the reader's `mut.lock` loses the race, then `num_copy=5` whether the read is before or after the reader's unlock; perhaps that's the case you and the OP had in mind.

Comment: @PeterCordes You missed the last sentence in the question. As for it you assumption *The reader could take and release the lock before the writer thread takes the lock* is not true. You have extended your comment, and you are right.

Comment: @273K: Oh yes, I did miss the first half of that sentence.  So yeah, the same precondition that guarantees the reader sees `num == 5` with normal locking also guarantees it here.  The `unlock` is a release operation on `mut`, and `mut.lock` is an acquire, so we have a happens-before, same as if we'd done a release store / acquire load on `atomic<bool> data_ready`

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Do the release-acquire visibility guarantees of std::mutex apply to only the critical section?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58021311), but the answers there are heavily standardese, without highlighting the key point in plain English, that the unlock is a release operation and the next acquire syncs-with it, creating a happens-before.  I'll edit to fix that.

Comment: Specific to here: Actually it's pretty simple: If the writer locks the mutex before the reader tries, as you describe, the reader has to wait until the writer unlocks. As the latter occurs only *after* writing the value the reader is guaranteed to read 5, whether it does so protected or not. The more interesting case is the other way round...

Comment: Side note : (almost) NEVER manually lock and unlock. Use std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock{mut};` (or std::unique_lock) If you leave your function while holding a manually locked mutex (add a return statement, or an exception is thrown) you end up not unlocking your mutex and this is bad!

Comment: Read more on how classes like scoped_lock work in C++ : [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)

Comment: Also what you probably need is a std::condition_variable (which is more of an inter thread signal). `std::mutex mtx; std::condition_variabable cv; bool new_data{false};`  Writer thread : `std::unique_lock lock{mtx}; num = 5; new_data = true; cv.notify_all();` and reader thread `std::unique_lock{mtx}; cv.wait_for([&]{ return new_data;}; new_data = false; int num_cpy = num;`